# How addContractListener works in hyperledger fabric 1.4 version

Tags: javascript, hyperledger-fabric

I'm using fabric version `1.4`. I have deploy my contract `fabcar` on first network. I have do some modification in that existing contract like add `SetEvent("initLedger",[]byte{"test"})`. And what I want is to listen these events using my below code but not able to fetch events. Here is my code:-

**CODE**

```
//connect to Fabric Network, but starting a new gateway
   const gateway = new Gateway();

   //use our config file, our peerIdentity, and our discovery options to connect to Fabric network.
   await gateway.connect(ccpPath, { wallet, identity: peerIdentity, discovery: { enabled: true, asLocalhost: true } });

   console.log('gateway connect');

   //connect to our channel that has been created on IBM Blockchain Platform
   const network = await gateway.getNetwork('mychannel');

   //connect to our insurance contract that has been installed / instantiated on IBM Blockchain Platform
   const contract = await network.getContract('fabcar');

await contract.addContractListener('my-contract-listener', 'InitLedger', (err, event, blockNumber, transactionId, status) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        return;
      }

      //convert event to something we can parse 
      event = event.payload.toString();
      event = JSON.parse(event)

      //where we output the TradeEvent
      console.log('************************ Start Trade Event *******************************************************');
      console.log(`make: ${event.type}`);
      console.log(`model: ${event.ownerId}`);
      console.log(`colour: ${event.id}`);
      console.log(`owner: ${event.description}`);
      console.log(`Block Number: ${blockNumber} Transaction ID: ${transactionId} Status: ${status}`);
      console.log('************************ End Trade Event ************************************');
    });
```

While I'm running this code in console it will print nothing. If I'm missing something or  any suggestions please welcome or suggest me.